# Incorrect padding when scrolled down

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The logo on this page loses the correct padding when scrolled down or up?
Here's the [site](http://www.nanoinformaticseducation.com/)
This is what i have :

```
element.style {
    padding-top: 27px;
    padding-bottom: 27px;
}
```

Comment: It took `padding` from a `js` script, like `jquery` or `javascript` , it set when scroll is `x` or `y` give `padding` to logo. you are site owner right? ok find that `padding` in your scripts and remove it.

Comment: I know what needs to be done, however i am unable to find the code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scrollPage() function in your script.js file comment or edit with 0 values the follow lines:

```
$('.navbar-brand').css({
    'padding-top': 19 + "px",
    'padding-bottom': 19 + "px"
});
```

Comment: I don't have scrollPage() function in my script.js. Should I add this function?

Comment: Yes you have, check in your js folder inside script.js file

Comment: I have commented out the line.`//$('.navbar-brand').css({ 'padding-top' : 0 + "px", 'padding-bottom' : 0 + "px" });` but i don't see any difference

Answer (score 1):

use `important` and `override css`. as I said in comment you can find that property in your script but if you can't or anything else you can use this rule:

```
.navbar>.container .navbar-brand {
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

**Update:** but look like `xzegga` find it on your script, better to use that answer to solve your problem.